# mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker

I am following this guide and I am about halfway down the guide in the Docker configuration section.

I am running Ubuntu 16 on my Odroid.

My Dockerfile is giving me an error.  Here is what I am using...

```
# Base image:
FROM ruby:2.4.0

# Install dependencies
#RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

# Set an environment variable where the Rails app is installed to inside of Doc$
ENV RAILS_ROOT /home/john/myapp
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT

# Set working directory, where the commands will be ran:
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# Gems:
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install
```

Here is the error I am getting.

```
Step 2/12 : ENV RAILS_ROOT /home/john/myapp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 67905f8bb273
Step 3/12 : RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT
 ---> Running in 4d368a5e6181
standard_init_linux.go:187: exec user process caused "exec format error"
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I'm not sure why $RAILS_ROOT is giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

> I am running Ubuntu 16 on my Odroid.

If I am not mistaken, the ODROID are ARM CPU devices. While Docker itself is compatible with ARM, you would need to use base images that are as well.

With that said, it looks like the ARM based images for the official Ruby image only exist as of 2.4.1: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/3078. You can try upgrading the base image to 2.4.1 and see what happens.

However, even though the official library may have ARM based images in the registry, I am not quite sure if there is a Docker version that supports switching of the arch for the same repository. I couldn't find any references to pulling multi-arch images.